# Trying to get Sims 4 to work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

So since yesterday I've been trying to get The Sims 4 working on this computer so that my little sister can play it but nothing is working.

I've finally gotten it to the point where Origin is online and we can sign in and I even finally got it to download and install the game but now I get error messages when I hit play.

Here are the errors:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00a0304d in 64-bit code (0x000000018009dd30).
Register dump:
 rip:000000018009dd30 rsp:000000000023f4a0 rbp:0000000000000000 eflags:00010212 (  R- --  I   -A- - )
 rax:0000000000a0304d rbx:0000000000000000 rcx:000000000000000a rdx:0000000000000002
 rsi:0000000000000001 rdi:0000000000000000  r8:000000017f6d67ab  r9:000000000023f658 r10:0000000000a0304d
 r11:0000000000000246 r12:0000000000600000 r13:0000000000600000 r14:000000000023f5a8 r15:0000000000600060
Stack dump:
0x000000000023f4a0:  0000000000000000 000000007b420000
0x000000000023f4b0:  0000000000010a10 000000007bd1c720
0x000000000023f4c0:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000023f4d0:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000023f4e0:  0000000000000000 00000000000000a0
0x000000000023f4f0:  000000000000009c 0000000000600000
0x000000000023f500:  00007fffff7e8000 0000000000000000
0x000000000023f510:  00007fffff7ef000 00000001400088b8
0x000000000023f520:  0000000180000000 00000000ffffffff
0x000000000023f530:  0000000000000098 0000000180046bcb
0x000000000023f540:  000000000023fbea 000000007b420000
0x000000000023f550:  000000000023f658 0000000000000098
Backtrace:
=>0 0x000000018009dd30 in igo64 (+0x9dd30) (0x0000000000000000)
  1 0x0000000180046bcb in igo64 (+0x46bca) (0x00000000ffffffff)
  2 0x0000000180047968 in igo64 (+0x47967) (0x00000000ffffffff)
  3 0x0000000140004922 in igoproxy64 (+0x4921) (0x00000000ffffffff)
  4 0x0000000140004a8e in igoproxy64 (+0x4a8d) (0x0000000000000157)
  5 0x0000000140005e51 in igoproxy64 (+0x5e50) (0x000000000023fe40)
  6 0x000000007b47c5cf in kernel32 (+0x5c5ce) (0x000000000023fe40)

  ....

00000158 TS4_x64.exe
    00000157    0
00000166 (D) z:\home\computer\playonlinux's virtual drives\origin\drive_c\program files\Origin\igoproxy64.exe
    000000f1    0
    0000016b    0
```

The full error message is [in this Google doc](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByYfI2LJOXrVek52ckdBTDZnNjg) and [a similar but slightly different one in this doc](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByYfI2LJOXrVVzFYZlNaM01Dclk)

I've become hellbent on making this work so any help is much appreciated.

I'm using wine 2.03 right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up getting to work and it turned out that the problem was the wine version. 2.19-staging makes the game work flawlessly!

Getting the game to install was interesting. I ended up installing the game on a Windows computer and moving the whole installation to the Linux PC in the folder where Origin installs the games and the game installed fine.

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Origin In Game under Application Settings.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you give us some direction!

Comment: [Under the Origin drop down menu.](https://imgur.com/a/Y23Hc)