# Sims 4 Ubuntu 16.04 issue (different solution needed)

Tags: wine, games

Similar situation as here: [Trying to get Sims 4 to work on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969122/trying-to-get-sims-4-to-work-on-ubuntu-16-04?newreg=4feaf45134d84b879e0b6f21f934c593) as in I get Origin online, sign in, and install Sims 4. Difference being that I get the same error message each time I try.
I need a different solution than the one listed in the previous question. Switching to staging does not work for me and neither does disabling Origin In-Game.
I tried installing all three vcrun2010 vcrun2013 vcrun2017, and succeed with the first two, but terminal gives me "Unknown arg vcrun2017"
for the last one.

I am using wine 2.21 (staging) and 32-bit, but I am getting no difference in the error besides a change in system information. The previous question has a problem with two error messages popping up, while I only get one.

I too am hellbent on getting this to work. Here is the error backtrace:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on execute access to 0x00000000 in 32-bit code (0x00000000).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:00000000 ESP:01a3e9dc EBP:01a3ea08 EFLAGS:00010202(  R- --  I   - - - )
 EAX:7b647dec EBX:7bd0e000 ECX:191a4dcf EDX:ffffffff
 ESI:7bd0e000 EDI:00340000
Stack dump:
0x01a3e9dc:  7b427c55 7b647dec 000104af 01a3e9ec
0x01a3e9ec:  7bca85a0 00340000 00000000 00000009
0x01a3e9fc:  0000000b f73cdbd7 7bd0e000 01a3eaf8
0x01a3ea0c:  7bcab97e 7b427c40 00340000 191a4dcf
0x01a3ea1c:  191a4dcf 00000001 01a3ea4c 7bccefd0
0x01a3ea2c:  7bd0e000 00000000 00000000 00000000
000c: sel=0067 base=00000000 limit=00000000 32-bit r-x
Backtrace:
=>0 0x00000000 (0x01a3ea08)
  1 0x7bcab97e in ntdll (+0x6b97d) (0x01a3eaf8)
  2 0x7bca857e RtlRaiseException+0x49() in ntdll (0x01a3eb18)
  3 0x7bcb393f in ntdll (+0x7393e) (0x01a3f368)
  4 0xf755f295 start_thread+0xe4() in libpthread.so.0 (0x01a3f428)
  5 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  6 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  7 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  8 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  9 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  10 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  11 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  12 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  13 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  14 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  15 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  16 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  17 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  18 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  19 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  20 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  21 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  22 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  23 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  24 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  25 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  26 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  27 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  28 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  29 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  30 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  31 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  32 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  33 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  34 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  35 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  36 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  37 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  38 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  39 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  40 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  41 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  42 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  43 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  44 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  45 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  46 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  47 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  48 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  49 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  50 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  51 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  52 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  53 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  54 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  55 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  56 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  57 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  58 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  59 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  60 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  61 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  62 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  63 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  64 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  65 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  66 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  67 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  68 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  69 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  70 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  71 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  72 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  73 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  74 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  75 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  76 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  77 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  78 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  79 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  80 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  81 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  82 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  83 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  84 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  85 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  86 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  87 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  88 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  89 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  90 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  91 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  92 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  93 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  94 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  95 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  96 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  97 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  98 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  99 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  100 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  101 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  102 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  103 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  104 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  105 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  106 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  107 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  108 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  109 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  110 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  111 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  112 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  113 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  114 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  115 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  116 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  117 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  118 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  119 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  120 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  121 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  122 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  123 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  124 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  125 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  126 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  127 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  128 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  129 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  130 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  131 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  132 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  133 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  134 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  135 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  136 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  137 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  138 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  139 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  140 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  141 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  142 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  143 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  144 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  145 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  146 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  147 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  148 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  149 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  150 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  151 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  152 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  153 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  154 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  155 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  156 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  157 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  158 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  159 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  160 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  161 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  162 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  163 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  164 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  165 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  166 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  167 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  168 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  169 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  170 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  171 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  172 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  173 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  174 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  175 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  176 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  177 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  178 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  179 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  180 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  181 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  182 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  183 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  184 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  185 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  186 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  187 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  188 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  189 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  190 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  191 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  192 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  193 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  194 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  195 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  196 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  197 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  198 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  199 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  200 0xf748905e __clone+0x6d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
0x00000000: -- no code accessible --
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (38 modules)
PE    400000- 1935000   Deferred        ts4
PE  10000000-1009a000   Deferred        activation
ELF 7b400000-7b7ee000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b420000-7b7ee000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bd2c000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc40000-7bd2c000   \               ntdll
ELF 7c000000-7c004000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7e20c000-7e32b000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e210000-7e32b000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e32b000-7e3a3000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e340000-7e3a3000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e3a3000-7e675000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e3b0000-7e675000   \               shell32
ELF 7e675000-7e6ee000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e680000-7e6ee000   \               advapi32
ELF 7e6ee000-7e81d000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e700000-7e81d000   \               gdi32
ELF 7e81d000-7ea00000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e830000-7ea00000   \               user32
ELF 7ea00000-7eae6000   Deferred        msvcr100<elf>
  \-PE  7ea20000-7eae6000   \               msvcr100
ELF 7eae6000-7ec00000   Deferred        msvcp100<elf>
  \-PE  7eb20000-7ec00000   \               msvcp100
ELF 7ed35000-7ed50000   Deferred        aclui<elf>
  \-PE  7ed40000-7ed50000   \               aclui
ELF 7ed50000-7ed63000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ed63000-7ed70000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ed70000-7ed8b000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ef8b000-7efe0000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe6000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF f739d000-f73a2000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f73a2000-f7558000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF f7559000-f7576000   Dwarf           libpthread.so.0
ELF f7576000-f7580000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF f7596000-f7767000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7769000-f778e000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f7790000-f7791000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\services.exe]
    000000b3    0
    00000065    0
    00000022    0
    0000001d    0
    00000013    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000011 winedevice.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\winedevice.exe]
    0000001c    0
    00000017    0
    00000016    0
    00000012    0
0000001a plugplay.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\plugplay.exe]
    0000001f    0
    0000001e    0
    0000001b    0
00000020 winedevice.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\winedevice.exe]
    00000029    0
    00000024    0
    00000023    0
    00000021    0
00000027 explorer.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\explorer.exe /desktop]
    0000002c    0
    0000002b    0
    0000002a    0
    00000028    0
00000063 rpcss.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\rpcss.exe]
    00000069    0
    00000068    0
    00000067    0
    00000066    0
    00000064    0
00000093 Origin.exe
    ["C:\Program Files\Origin\Origin.exe"  /AutoUpdate /AutoPatchGlobal /TelemOO /Installing /Installed:9.12.0.34172]
    000001e4    0
    000001e3    0
    000001c5    0
    0000012d    0
    0000011d    0
    00000113    0
    0000010d    0
    0000010c    0
    0000010b    0
    0000010a    0
    00000109    0
    00000107    0
    00000106    0
    00000105    0
    000000ff   15
    000000ec   15
    000000eb    0
    000000ea    0
    000000e9    0
    000000d6    0
    000000d2    0
    000000d1    0
    000000d0    0
    000000cf    0
    000000ce    0
    000000cd    0
    000000cc    0
    000000ae    0
    000000ad    0
    000000ac    0
    000000ab    0
    000000aa    0
    000000a9    0
    000000a8    0
    000000a5    0
    000000a4    0
    000000a3    0
    000000a2    0
    000000a0    0
    0000009f    0
    0000009e    2
    0000009d    2
    0000009c    0
    00000094    0
000000b1 OriginClientService.exe
    ["C:\Program Files\Origin\OriginClientService.exe"]
    000000c0    0
    000000bf    0
    000000be    0
    000000bd    2
    000000bc    2
    000000b8    0
    000000b7    0
    000000b6    0
    000000b5    0
    000000b4    0
    000000b2    0
000000ba OriginClientService.exe
    ["C:\Program Files\Origin\OriginClientService.exe" C:\Program Files\Origin\OriginClientService.exe -args:jEkmlROMvIyOo1wFMaPaCmElDTl4fCya]
    000000c9    0
    000000c7    0
    000000c6    0
    000000c5    0
    000000c4    2
    000000c3    2
    000000bb    0
000001e6 (D) C:\Program Files\Origin Games\The Sims 4\Game\Bin\TS4.exe
    ["C:\Program Files\Origin Games\The Sims 4\Game\Bin\TS4.exe"   ]
    000001e8    0 <==
    000001e7    0
000001eb explorer.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\explorer.exe /desktop]
    000001ef    0
    000001ee    0
    000001ed    0
    000001ec    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-2.21 (Staging)
    Platform: i386
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.10.0-42-generic
```

A screenshot of the error message that pops up when I click play.

[image: ]]

Comment: Your exception is different than in the one in the other question, so I think you should add that to your question to get it reopened.

Comment: Did you install the winetricks artefacts `vcrun2010`, `vcrun2013`, and `vcrun2017` like the [WineApp DB entry suggests](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33219)?

Comment: I tried to edit it to fit my exception but i'm not exactly sure what my exception is besides face values, so hopefully it did enough. I updated the question with information about visual c++.

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear to me which of the 2 answers in the called duplicate you attempted.

Comment: I tried both of them; I turned off In-Game in the application settings in Origin and switched from wine stable 2.0.3 to wine staging 2.21.

Comment: I'm still not so sure what I need to fix in  my question to get it open.